# Erro no postgre tentando acessar externamente

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, ip, pgadmin, internet

Estou usando o NO-IP para conectar a um servidor interno no meu escritório . Ja liberei a porta 5432 no firewall da maquina e também ja configurei os arquivos pg_hba.conf e o postgresql.conf (vou deixar os 2 aqui) . Ja testei a porta pelo site [inserir a descrição do link aqui](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) e tudo ocorre perfeitamente . Porém quando tento acessar o banco pelo pgadmin de outra maquina usando meu IP externo como host ele me retorna o seguinte erro :

> server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.

Ele até parece conectar , pois no painel de controle da maquina(servidor) indica uma conexão nova com meu IP externo , porém após alguns instantes ele desconecta e mostra o erro na outra maquina(na qual eu estou tentando usar o pgadmin para conectar com o servidor) .

pg_hba.conf

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust

postgresql.conf

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;

Comment: Você não especificou como está a rede. Se sua rede possui NAT, é possível que seja necessário um encaminhamento de porta do seu roteador/switch para o IP de rede do servidor de banco.

Comment: Ja fiz o redirecionamento de porta em todos os roteadores aqui ... E nos testes que eu faço eu consigo me comunicar com a porta TCP 5432 , só no postgre que da esse erro ...

Comment: A autenticação não trará problemas na conexão com o banco de dados, o IP sim. Tente colocar na linha do pg_hba.conf `host all all all md5`

Comment: Continua dando o mesmo erro . Eu tentei usar o pgadmin na casa de um amigo acessando o banco aqui e deu certo ... So não funciona quando eu tento acessar daqui usando o ip externo . Quando eu tento acessar pela rede interna funciona .